# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'knuminput'

Tags: qt, ubuntu, pyqt5

я пытаюсь разобраться с `PyQt5` и когда я запускаю готовую программу т.е файл с `gui` 
возникает ошибка с виджетами, которые начинаются на `"k"`

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'knuminput'
```

Много раз уже переустанавливал `Qt`. Я уже не знаю, что делать?

[image: скрин 2-х файлов[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaCCI.png)

Comment: спасибо, за правку

Comment: Нужно установленное KDE чтоб это работало.

Comment: у меня уже есть KDE, но все равно, спасибо)

Comment: но не там где нужно)

Comment: да) я просто недавно линукс установил, так что не всё понимаю)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если pyqt5 ставилось через pip, то там отдельная сборка qt не связаная с системной. На системной qt установленны виджеты kde. На той что встроенна в pyqt5 - нет.

Вариант  использовать версию из пакета python3-pyqt5. Так получится сделать загрузку виджетов через ui файл.

Но это не сработает с загрузкой при компиляции ui в py файл. Понадобится сделать обертку для них через sip.

Слишком много возни, используй те что без k

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо за потраченное время) Я тоже думаю просто забыть про эти виджеты. Я же день на это потратил.